# Alternative to BitmapImage to load a PNG

Tags: wpf, metadata, bitmapimage

On a WPF project, I need to set a ImageSource property from a local Resource.
I am trying to use the following code:

```
   var bmp = new BitmapImage();
   bmp.BeginInit();
   bmp.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Identicons/no_user.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
   bmp.EndInit();
   Avatar = bmp;
```

Where Avatar is defined before as:

```
private ImageSource myAvatar;
```

The problem is that BitmapImage does not support MetaData information, that the source image have (it was created with Paint.net) so it throws a error. The error is the following:

> Metadata = 'bmp.Metadata' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NotSupportedException'

So I believe that I need alternatives to BitmapImage to properly load the desired image.

As a end note, using the same image inside xaml, directly in a "source" property it works fine.
Thank you

Comment: Build Action 'Resource' didn't work, but 'Embedded Resource' did :)

Comment: The correct Build Action for assembly resource files (as loaded by Resource File Pack URIs) is *Resource*, not *Embedded Resource*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `BitmapImage`, `BitmapFrame` supports the `Metadata` property:

So you may replace

```
Avatar = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));
```

by

```
Avatar = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(...));
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe(v=vs.100).aspx):

> BitmapFrame provides additional functionality not defined by
>   BitmapSource ... BitmapFrame also supports the writing of metadata
>   information by using the Metadata property or the
>   CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter method.

Comment: Although this seams the correct answer, the return is null (no exception is shown), and I have sure that the image is available. Using: Avatar = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Identicons/no_user.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: Besides that the UriKind parameter isn't  necessary, did you make sure that the image file is part of your Visual Studio project, as mentioned in my comment to your question?

Comment: Yes it is. Is is located as a Resource. I even changed the name to another (wrong name) and a error is thrown about the missing file in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the path to the image it can be done by below using Image Control,

### XAML

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}"></BitmapImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

### VM

```
public ViewerViewModel()// Constructor 
    {
        ImagePath = @"..\Images\Untitled.jpg";// Change the image path based on your input.
    }
    private string _ImagePath = string.Empty;
    public string ImagePath {
        get { return _ImagePath; }
        set { _ImagePath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Comment: I am adding the ImageSource into a property in a Class, so not Image Control available. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
This was inside a Class with the property:

```
    private ImageSource myAvatar;
....

    public ImageSource Avatar
    {
        set { myAvatar = Avatar; }
        get { return myAvatar; }
    }
```

And I was trying to change the Avatar (that sets the myAvatar through the set).
I do not understand why, but changing directly the myAvatar works. For example doing:

```
BitmapSource image = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Identicons/no_user.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
myAvatar = image;
```

Is ok, but:

```
BitmapSource image = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Identicons/no_user.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
Avatar = image;
```

Always sets Avatar as null.
This is a method inside a class. I would appreciate to understand why as it is not clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: The property setter should be `set { myAvatar = value; }`. Otherwise the property is always set to the value it already has, i.e. `null`.

Comment: Correct, and the same Class have more than 10 'set { something = value; }'. Do not know how I missed this one, and I though was related with the image source... Thank you.